# Output is not displaying in node js

Tags: node.js

I am new in nodejs. I am trying to run my first program but the output is not showing. please help me out to resolve this issue.

```
 console.log("hello world")

Error showing 
 node HelloWorld.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Dell\nodeex\HelloWorld.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)        
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Can you show a list of the files in the directory you're in?

Comment: see if this file actually exist C:\Users\Dell\nodeex\HelloWorld.js